# Why attr id not assigned to form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please advise why this code doesn't work. The ID of the form should appear in input field as value.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("form").attr(id, "message");
  $("input").val($("form").attr('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text">
</form>
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: Look at the error message when you run the code.

Comment: What's the value of your `id` *variable*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes for the `id`

`$("form").attr("id", "message");`